# monitor if variable is growing compared to others bash in the last readings

Tags: bash, numbers, compare

I'm doing a script in bash to monitor different changes to a variable ( a number). I want to get , let's say 10 readings, and determine if the number is growing, remaining the same or  getting lower. The readings will be like : 1-2-4-3-6-7-9-8-6-9-7.... my script needs to know if the number is increasing or decreasing.

Comment: Please provide what you've implemented so far

Answer (score 1):

Store the previous value in a variable and compare the values numerically:

```
#! /bin/bash

for n in 1 2 4 3 3 6 7 9 8 6 9 7 ; do
    echo $n
    if [[ $previous ]] ; then
        if (( previous < n )) ; then
            echo Growing
        elif (( previous > n )) ; then
            echo Getting lower
        fi
    fi
    previous=$n
done
```